# how to move a variable's value from jsf's bean page (i.e, bean.java) to another java class?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, javabeans

how to move a variable's value from jsf's bean page (i.e, bean.java) to another java class?  when i tried to do that, the value assinged to the variable in the second java class is NULL.,

I have used primefaces UI framework(something like jsf) and assigned every fields value in to a bean class. the value assigned to every variable in bean class is proper. but when i tried to move those values to another .java file. The scope of the variable dies, and the value is NULL. Check out my codings..

**LOGIN.XHTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">


<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>

<p:panel header="Login" style="">
<h:form>

<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
<h:outputText value="Username"></h:outputText>
<p:inputText id="userName" value="#{loginBean.userName}"></p:inputText>
<h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
<p:password id="password" value="#{loginBean.password}"></p:password>
<p:commandButton value="Sign in" ajax="false" actionListener="#{loginBean.forward}"></p:commandButton>



</h:panelGrid>

</h:form> 

</p:panel>
</h:body>


</html>
```

**loginBean.java**

```
package bean;
import receive.*;
public class loginBean {
public String userName;
public String password;
public String getUserName() {
return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword() {
return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}
public void forward()
{
System.out.println(getUserName());
receiveclass r=new receiveclass();
r.dbc();
}
}
```

**receiveclass.java**

```
package receive;
import bean.loginBean; 
public class receiveclass {
loginBean lb=new loginBean();

public void dbc()
{
  String s= lb.getUserName();
  String p=lb.getPassword();
  System.out.println(s);
  System.out.println(p);
  //System.out.println("hi");

}

}
```

output is,

if i give as admin, admin in text fields

i am receiving  as

**admin
null
null**

Comment: Dont know why the scope of the variable dies when it is moved to another .java file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manually creating the beans instead of letting JSF manage the beans. Manually created beans won't be used by JSF at all. You need to let JSF auto-create and manage those beans. You can access other JSF managed beans by injecting it as [`@ManagedProperty`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html):

In your particular case, the following should work:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    @ManagedProperty
    private ReceiveClass receiveClass;

    public void forward() {
        receiveClass.dbc(this);
    }

    // Add/generate getters and setters.
}
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ReceiveClass {

    public void dbc(LoginBean loginBean) {
        System.out.println(loginBean.getUserName());
    }

}
```

*(Note that I fixed the code to adhere the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) properly. Class names ought to start with uppercase)*

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Injecting managed beans in each other](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther)

Answer (score 0):

in your receiveclass you create a completely new instance of loginBean. Values can only be null.

I do it this way: I created a Java class in which I have static functions like this one

```
public class JSFHelper 
{
   public static Object getMyObject(String objname, Class<?> classname )
   {    
      FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      ELContext elCtx = fCtx.getELContext();
      ExpressionFactory ef = fCtx.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
      ValueExpression ve = 
        ef.createValueExpression(elCtx, "#{" + objname+ "}",classname);
      return (Object) ve.getValue(elCtx);
   }
}
```

If I need a value from another Bean it would look like this in your receiveclass:

```
public class receiveclass 
{        

   public void dbc()        
   {          
       loginBean lb=(loginBean)JSFHelper.getMyObject("loginBean",loginBean.class);
       String s= lb.getUserName();          
       String p=lb.getPassword();          
       System.out.println(s);          
       System.out.println(p);          
       //System.out.println("hi");    
   }                
}
```